# Slate Editor Issue: Cannot resolve a DOM point from Slate point: {"path":[0,0],"offset":30}

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, slate

Description:
The error is thrown when I add a custom link into a slate editor at current cursor position and use tab or space after the inserted link.

This is the code I am using to add my custom link DOM element into slate editor at current cursor position.

```js
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  var linkDOMElement = document.getElementById('insertLink');
  if (!linkDOMElement) {
    var range;
    if (event.data && (typeof event.data === 'string' || event.data instanceof String) && event.data.includes("atProspectId") && window.getSelection) {
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      var html = event.data;

      // create a span dom element
      var newElement = document.createElement('span');
      newElement.id = 'insertLink';
      newElement.innerHTML = html;

      // insert created dom element named newElement at current cursor position
      range.insertNode(newElement);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Scenario:
We have a script which attaches our custom icon to the outreach email editor and apparently outreach email editor uses slate editor. After clicking upon this icon, it opens our extension application in a new tab[for now]. If user clicks on "INSERT LINK" button, link should be inserted at current cursor position which is happening as expected. But, I am unable to click the link and write any texts further after the insertion. If I use space or tab after the link insertion, this error shows up. You could see this clearly in the attached video.

Environment:

Slate Version: No idea as this is happening in third party website
Operating System: Windows
Browser: Chrome

To see how the above error is thrown, you could click on the following link and watch 43 secs video.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/86764119/146716602-657bf5ce-535a-4bdb-bb36-64c3fbb8d548.mp4

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `contentEditable` to `false` and the `userSelect` CSS property to `'none'`.

Before `range.insertNode`, add the following code:

```
newElement.contentEditable = 'true';
newElement.style.userSelect = 'none';
```

In [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/3421#issuecomment-591259117), the Slate developers explain that you have to set these properties to avoid this error.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - in the text you say `contentEditable` should be `false` but in the code sample you set it to `true` (in fact you set it to the string `'true'` rather than a boolean value)